# Why is OS X Maverics upgrade size the same as a fresh install?

Tags: macos

I have OSX 10.7 that came installed on my MacBook by default, and decided to upgrade to 10.9 Mavericks.

The download is ~5GB in size, if I have a network disconnect I am worried it will begin form the start. Is there a way I cam download the upgrade of smaller size or do I have to get new installation in any case, and then how should I have a resumable download?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>You seem to have two questions here…</sup>

> Why is OS X Mavericks upgrade size the same as a fresh install?

There's only one installer. Unlike Windows, there's a single OS X installer that is able to install on and/or upgrade any machine capable of running Mavericks, from any prior version of OS X all the way back to 10.6.

> Is there a way I can download the upgrade of smaller size or do I have to get new installation in any case, and then how should I have a resumable download?

No, the OS X Mavericks install is the single installer available — there's no smaller copy.

The Mac App Store *does* support resumable download, so don't worry about your internet connection dropping. It will pause/resume the download automatically.

Comment: what is the location where the dmg file is getting downloaded ?

Comment: @san The DMG is inside the app package.

Comment: at the moment , the download is in progress, and I do not see the app package in `/Appliations` which is what I asked where is the in progress file being downloaded ?

Comment: @san `/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.appstore/`.

Answer (score 1):

Mac App Store downloads support pausing and continuing after connectivity problems. You can safely download Mavericks without fear of having to restart the download in the case of any disconnections.